# How to send a message to another user via Bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am writing a shell script, and I need to send a message to the other user.

If I write `write user1` in `trem`, and then write the message and use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>, the message will send to `user1`'s `trem` successfully.

But I want to use a .sh file to send the message to `user1` automatically, and I encountered the problem. I need to write the message by myself when I use the command `write user1` each time.

Now I want to save the message in the script and every time I send the message, I don't need to write the message again. How should I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pipe a file/string into it like

```
echo "message" | write <user>
```